# gorm unsupported destination, should be slice or struct

Tags: go, go-gorm

When I use this way, it has no error

```golang
var result model.Captcha
fmt.Printf("Type: %T", result)
if err := DB.Model(&model.Captcha{}).Where("id = ?", randNum).Find(&result).Error; err != nil{
    return nil, err
}
```

But if I use the following way, error occours

```golang
var result *model.Captcha
fmt.Printf("Type: %T", result)
if err := DB.Model(&model.Captcha{}).Where("id = ?", randNum).Find(result).Error; err != nil{
    return nil, err
}
```

`result` in the first way type is `model.Captcha`, then `&result` in Find(&result) type is `*model.Captcha`, the second way `result`  type is `*model.Captcha`, but the second way has error?

Could anyone tell me why, thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define result as `result := &models.Captcha{}`, in this way you can use `.Find(result)` without using `&`.

please check [this go tour link](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1) out for a better understanding of pointers.

When you declare `var result *models.Captcha`, the compiler creates a nil pointer, but with & you can generate a pointer to underlying models.Captcha, then gorm can use this handle to bind SQL data to the struct.

Comment: First, thanks for answering my question, but I have never seen definition like `var result &models.Captcha`,  and of cource I tried this one, but the IDE says it is wrong!

Comment: sorry, check the post aging, I corrected it. It should be `result := &models.Captcha{}`

Comment: thanks, it works, I used the first way last time, and it seems to work fine, but this time error occours.  By the way, if the destination is a slice, how should I define it, should it be `var result []model.Captcha`, and `Find(&result)`?

Comment: yeah, you can use `var list []models.Captcha` and `.Find(&list)` or `list := &[]models.Captcha{}` and `.Find(list)`, the first one is better.